# Not enough storage to complete this operation in SQL Server CE

Tags: sql-server-ce, windows-ce

I'm developing wince headless device application, in that I have two applications both should be running at a time and both are accessing same SQL Server CE `.sdf` file.

If I run one by one its works fine. But while running both at a time SQL Server CE exception is raising that

> Not enough storage to complete this operation.

This is my code:

```
private void WriteToBD(string _serialNum, string _dataBytes)
{
   try
   {
      using (_con = new SqlCeConnection(@"Data Source=\NandFlash\PLCPackets.sdf;"))
      {
         _con.Open();

         string str = "insert into PLCPacket(SerialNum,Data) values('" + _serialNum + "','" + _dataBytes + "')";

         using (SqlCeCommand _cmd = new SqlCeCommand(str, _con))
         {
            //_cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
            int rowsAffected = _cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
         }
      }
   }
   catch (Exception ex)
   {
      LogData.WriteFile(ex.Message);
   }
   finally
   {
      _con.Close();
      _con.Dispose();
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `mode=read write` explicitly in the connection string. You can find more information in [this MSDN reference document](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlserverce.sqlceconnection.connectionstring.aspx).